# Error compiling twain.h version 2.3 in Visual Studio Premium 2013

Tags: function-pointers, twain

My project type in Visual Studio Premium 2013 is a C++ Library

These lines of code in twain.h generate this: Error: Function returning function is not allowed

TW_HANDLE TW_CALLINGSTYLE DSM_MemAllocate(TW_UINT32);
typedef TW_HANDLE(TW_CALLINGSTYLE *DSM_MEMALLOCATE)(TW_UINT32 _size);

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you explain more your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the source of the compiler errors, which was 2 #includes I had put at the top of twain.h.  Once I removed those, it compiles successfully.